# Bot - How to return a newline from Bot to both skype preview and skype web app

Tags: newline, botframework

I have a Bot app that returns a newline just fine to the Skype preview windows 10 app, using \n\n.  However, when I display the message in the web app https://web.skype.com/en/?ecsoverride=developer, it does nor respect the newline breaks and represents it as an ongoing string.

I do not see in the help here: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html
...how to represent a newline regardless of what the client will be - is there some newline that can be used for any client that will receive the message from my bot?  If I add something like 
 it shows as that text in my skype windows 10 app instead of a newline - I'm looking for some newline that works on any client.

Any ideas?

Comment: \n\n still works for me in skype web app

Answer (score 8):

**Update for 3.5 version**
putting to string `\n\n` creates a new paragraph. Like the following:

`"Paragraph1_text/n/nParagraph2_text"` results in

```
Paragraph1_text
Paragraph2_text
```

**Older versions**

I found out that putting **two spaces** + **NewLine symbol** solves the problem(C# code):

```
return $"some text:  {Environment.NewLine}text from new paragraph"
```

Or

```
return $"some text: \ntext from new paragraph"
```

The result is

```
some text:
text from new paragraph
```

This works for both: Microsoft Bot Framework emulator and Skype chat

Comment: Seems does not work in newest versions, any other ideas?

Comment: Yep, seems like they fixed it. I've just verified: "paragraph \n\n new paragraph" does work, I'll update answer

Answer (score 7):

Inserting HTML line break `<br/>` works!

Answer (score 5):

I use two new lines with a ["zero width non-joiner"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) unicode character.
=> `\n\n\u200C`
I successfully tested it in Facebook, Skype, Webchat, Emulator.

It also works , if you want blank lines!

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `\n\u200C<br>` works.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\r\n` to the string being sent works well for many clients.

Answer (score 0):

Send multi-line replys or send multiple replies to make it look multi-lined

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/33